# Cognos Report Keyword Search

Tags: cognos-10

I need to provide a keyword search option in a Cognos report.
I have 4 text box prompts for keywords. 
I need a solution where I filter the details field based on up to 4 keywords entered.
The filter expression I tried is:

`IF (?p_Details1? IS NOT NULL) THEN ( IF (?p_Details2? IS NOT NULL) THEN ( IF (?p_Details3? IS NOT NULL) THEN ( IF (?p_Details4? IS NOT NULL) THEN (UPPER([DETAILS]) CONTAINS (UPPER(?p_Details1?)) OR UPPER([DETAILS]) CONTAINS (UPPER(?p_Details2?)) OR UPPER([DETAILS]) CONTAINS (UPPER(?p_Details3?)) OR UPPER([DETAILS]) CONTAINS (UPPER(?p_Details4?))) ELSE (UPPER([DETAILS]) CONTAINS (UPPER(?p_Details1?)) OR UPPER([DETAILS]) CONTAINS (UPPER(?p_Details2?)) OR UPPER([DETAILS]) CONTAINS (UPPER(?p_Details3?))) ) ELSE (UPPER([DETAILS]) CONTAINS (UPPER(?p_Details1?)) OR UPPER([DETAILS]) CONTAINS (UPPER(?p_Details2?))) ) ELSE (UPPER([DETAILS]) CONTAINS (UPPER(?p_Details1?))) ) ELSE (1=1)`

If one of the text box prompts is null the report returns all records. So appears to be is ignoring my if statements. Works if all text box prompts have data.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This filter should work for you:

```
(?p_Details1? IS NOT NULL AND UPPER([DETAILS]) CONTAINS (UPPER(?p_Details1?)))
OR 
(?p_Details2? IS NOT NULL AND UPPER([DETAILS]) CONTAINS (UPPER(?p_Details2?)))
OR 
(?p_Details3? IS NOT NULL AND UPPER([DETAILS]) CONTAINS (UPPER(?p_Details3?)))
OR 
(?p_Details4? IS NOT NULL AND UPPER([DETAILS]) CONTAINS (UPPER(?p_Details4?)))
OR 
(?p_Details1? IS NULL AND ?p_Details2? IS NULL AND ?p_Details3? IS NULL AND ?p_Details4? IS NULL)
```

It might be helpful to think of a filter as a test that Cognos will apply to every row. It will either keep the row (true) or discard it (false). With relational database sources, it doesn't actually work that way internally but it does in effect.

The filter first checks to see if the first prompt has value and the [Details] data item contains the prompt value. If it does, it includes the row and moves on to the next row. If it doesn't, it moves to the next part of the OR statement which tests the second prompt. If the second prompt has value and the [Details] data item contains the prompt value the row is kept and it moves on to the next row. This is repeated for all four of the parameters.

If none of those expressions return true then and only then is the last part evaluated. This expression checks to see if all prompts are NULL. If so, all rows are returned.